# How do you calculate epoch time based on EST in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get today's day combine it with a $Time variable that I will get from some where else, cobine today and time, then convert them to epoch.

This is what I have:

```
$Time='16:26:00';
$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('EST'));
$today=$now->format('Y-m-d');
$today= $today . ' '. $Time;
$today=new DateTime($today, new DateTimeZone('EST'));
$today=date_format($today, 'U');
$today=$today*1000;
```

when I echo the today, I am getting time stamp that is 4 hours ahead of me, any ideas what I might be missing here?

Comment: As an aside, realize that 'EST' will produce the wrong time much of the year. If you need to be timezone aware, look up the [appropriate timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix time is always calculated in UTC (see [the definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)), so it looks like `date_format($today, 'U')` is adjusting the time zone back to UTC.

If you want to modify your unix timestamp with a time zone, you could use [`getOffset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php) to get the time zone offset from UTC. This value is in seconds so you can just add it to your unix timestamp.

Note that the result would no longer be a unix timestamp.

If you only ever need to deal with EST you could just subtract `18000` seconds (or `14400` seconds for EDT).

Comment: if I do this, #$today=$today->getOffset($today); it is reseting to 1970

Comment: `getOffset` gives the offset between two timezones, so you need to do `$todayInGMT->getOffset($todayInEST)` to get the correct value. You'll then need to do the subtraction manually. If you try to format the result with `'U'` it will just go back to GMT.